# Subgroups of $P=\{z\in\mathbb{C} : z^{2n}=1 \;\mbox{for some}\; n\geq 0\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, complex-numbers

> Investigate the subgroups of $P$ where
>   $$P=\{z\in\mathbb{C} : z^{2n}=1 \;\mbox{for some}\; n\geq 0\}.$$
>   In particular, investigate the finitely generated subgroups and the infinite subgroups. What are the factor groups of $P$ like?

I don't actually understand this, can anyone explain what I'm being asked and offer a solution or some help? Thanks.

Comment: It is a bit vague, but try and answer at least the following: 1) are the finitely generated subgroups always finite, or could they be infinite? 2) are the finitely generated subgroups always cyclic? 3) are there proper infinite subgroups? 4) show that $z\mapsto z^k$ (for a fixed integer $k$) is a homomorphism from $P$ to itself, 5) is it injective? surjective? Kernel? Quotients by kernels?

Comment: I wonder why they said $z^{2n}$ instead of just $z^n$. If there's some exponent (possibly odd), then, by squaring the equation, there's also an even exponent $2n$. You may get this problem in connection to the topic [roots of unity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity).

Comment: $P \cong \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg : unlikely, since $P$ is clearly countable while $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ is uncountable. I think you're confusing $P$ with the entire unit circle.

Comment: You have that $P=\langle e^{\frac{i\pi}{n}}\rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}_{2n}$. Now, you know everything about $\mathbb{Z}_{2n}$ and you are done.